# Dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10

Tags: boot, grub2, bash, windows, uefi

i installed ubuntu along with windows 10 but everytime i boot i get the grub minimal bash, if i exit it with "exit" it boots to windows.
I already started a linux live session and run boot-repair, but it said it was succesfull but i still end up in grub bash. 
I miss the screen where you can choose if you want to boot windows or linux... 
I guess this is a common problem but i already spend a few hours getting it installed (UEFI) so i need any help. Will look back in this thread in the morning.

Comment: Maybe use the `boot-repair` CD/USB to reinstall GRUB on the drive.

Comment: Yeah, i get a input not supported floating around my screen when i try to run boot repair.

Answer (score 1):

Since Boot Repair is failing, I recommend you try the following:

1. If you haven't already done so, disable Secure Boot.
2. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R image of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
3. Prepare a boot medium from the files you've just downloaded.
4. Boot using the rEFInd boot medium. It should present options to boot both Windows and Ubuntu.
5. Test your boot images. If you can boot Ubuntu, and ideally both OSes, proceed....
6. Boot Ubuntu.
7. Install a boot manager/boot loader:

   - If you're satisfied with rEFInd, you can install it to your hard disk via the PPA or Debian package, as described on its downloads page.
   - If you prefer GRUB, you can try to fix its installation manually. This will require some expertise, but it should be possible to do. Unfortunately, it's not clear to me what's going wrong, so I can't offer any specific suggestions.
   - You could also install any of a number of other EFI boot loaders for Linux, as I summarize on [this page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders)

If you want to use GRUB and need more help, post the URL that Boot Repair provides. That points to system-specific diagnostic information that might provide some clue about what's going wrong. Without such information, any GRUB-repair suggestion will be a shot in the dark.

Comment: Hey, i already made a fresh install of ubuntu and then windows, and booted to ubuntu via bios and ran boot repair, somehow it works and i have a working grub now. Still i appreciate your help and your refind tool!